# How to get users based on role?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, asp.net-membership

How could users in a "customer" role be retrieved from a MembershipUserCollection?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Roles.GetUsersInRole` returns a `string[]` of user names in a role. If you really want the `MembershipUser` objects, you can use:

```
var list = Roles.GetUsersInRole("roleName").Select(Membership.GetUser).ToList()
```

Of course, this is performance intensive as it hits the database once for every user.

If you are willing to give up provider-independence, you can query the underlying database directly and perform a join on the database server to get all users in a specific role.

Comment: missed <roleManager enabled="true" /> in web.config

Answer (score 1):

Go through this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.findusersinrole.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For binding to a `ListBox` you can use:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetUsersInRole("Role_Name");
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the RoleProvider class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx

it has a FindUsersInRole method

Comment: Please note FindUsersInRole accepts two parameters the second of which is a string that every user name should contain (i.e. LIKE) in order to be matched. It is a stupid method that cannot be used to find _all_ users in a role whatever their user name.

Comment: @dpant RoleProvider is an abstract class! The example on the link in my answer is exactly that "an example" - you define how the method works and what it returns by extending the RoleProvider class and completely the abstract methods so if you wish to ignore the second parameter and just pass in Null you can. I suggest you take the time to understand how these things work before posting meaningless comments.