# How to access informations of the membership users with MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website with a member section. There's also a admin to manage the users. What I want is that the admin sees the informations of the other users, like username and email.

For now, the registration page asks to users a username, a password and an email following [this tutorial](http://www.itorian.com/2012/11/adding-email-details-field-in.html). It memorises those in the DB just find, in the `UserProfile` Table. My problem is to access them. I knew how to do it with MVC3 with `Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()` and with a `where` to specify the request.

But, in MVC4, `Membership.GetAllUsers()` is not permitted as I understand. I have tried a lot of different ways found on the web, but none solve my problem. The best I've found is to get only the userName, found [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779264/how-to-get-users-based-on-role)  :

`var model = Roles.GetUsersInRole("StatusWaiting").Select(Membership.GetUser).ToList();`

where the `"statusWaiting"` is the role of the users I look for in my DB. But, with this (and some others with the same result), I have the EmailID that appears in the model, but it is always empty.

Does someone know how to achieve this? I'm still looking for it but I haven't found anything yet.

EDIT : If there's is another way to achieve this I'm mind opened

EDIT2 : With the line above, I get MemberShipUser with fields like : Comment, CreationDate,Email,IsApproved,..., ProviderName,...,UserName. So I strating to think that the table where I put the email at the registration is not the same than the one I'm trying to get informations. But I don't figure out which one else it could be

Comment: Where are you storing the user data?

Comment: I store them in the UserProfile of the DB of the DefaultConnection connectionString

Comment: You can just query that table in the DB then.

Comment: How? I tried many ways but the email field is always empty

Comment: Post the code you're using to create a user then. There's probably something wrong there.

Comment: ­`WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Email = model.Email});
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName,model.Password);return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` But i doubt it is the problem because I see the email in the db, I might just use a wrong query

Comment: the first thing I tried was : `var model = Roles.GetUsersInRole("StatusWaiting").Select(Membership.GetUser);//.ToList();` because I want the people which have StatusWaiting as role

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29675/discussion-between-lopezbertoni-and-castors33)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the role is "statusWaiting" then you can get the Roles using:

```
var model = Roles.GetUsersInRole("statusWaiting"); //Note the case
```

If the DB is populated correctly, then the error is your query.

EDIT:

The method signature from the default Role Provider is:

```
public string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
```

That's the reason you only get the username in the query. If you want more data then query your db directly, without using the Role Provider. Some code like the one below should help.

```
var query = db.UserTableName.Where(x => x.Role == "statusWaiting");
```

Comment: I guess it is yes. But with this line, I only get a string[] of the userName

Comment: that exactly my problem, I don't know how to really, directly, access to the UserProfile table because it's a table that visual automaticly make. I'm trying to search for a solution but I haven't found anything yet

Comment: Take a look at this: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx